# How do I prevent certain objects from receiving the raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, raycasting

I'm using the following code to perform a raycast and detect the GameObjects that are hit:

```
var eventDataCurrentPosition = new PointerEventData(EventSystem.current);
eventDataCurrentPosition.position = screenPosition;
var results = new List<RaycastResult>();
EventSystem.current.RaycastAll(eventDataCurrentPosition, results);
```

However, I want only certain objects to be hit by the `EventSystem.current.RaycastAll`. Is there any way to allow only certain GameObjects to receive the raycast?

Comment: It looks like you're doing a raycast on the UI only... is this your intention? You can add a hitmask that would make the ray only collide with objects that belong to the layers you select (but the above code won't work for that, hence asking if you want to only do it for the UI).

Comment: Yes.. I want to hit only the Buttons available

Comment: What do you want to do with the results of the raycast? If your intention is to drive menus/the game then you should probably be using the `Click()` functions on each button that are exposed within the Inspector.

Comment: I want to get a callback that the user has gazed at that specific button. It is a VR app

Comment: RaycastAll gives you all the hits. Why don't you simply filter the results yourself, like `results.Where(result => IsSuitable(result))`?

Comment: @ThomasHilbert tried it by looping through the result but I would like to achieve a solution that will prevent loops

Comment: Why would you want to prevent loops?

Comment: It would be more efficient to loop over the results using Linq than write 10 lines of code that achieves the same thing but doesn't loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways, one you can separate each UI categories to different Canvases and raycast from different graphicRaycaster component every time your need changes.

Or, I think the graphicRaycaster and EventSystem.current.RaycastAl both return an array of all UI objects hit, so why not just filter out manually by script based on their tags or so.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a CanvasGroup component to the UI elements you don't want to hit with the raycast. CanvasGroup has the option "block raycasts". Just set it to false and it should do the job.